# Subversion User Removal

Tags: svn, authentication

I'm taking over a server from a developer who has disappeared, and who has the system set up using Subversion. I have never used Subversion, but need to make sure he cannot get in using it. I do have su login.

My question is this:

Is there a way for root to modify/remove Subversion users, without logging in through Subversion?

If this doesn't make sense, it's mainly because I do not understand how Subversion operates, and therefore cannot ask the question correctly.

Comment: you should really give a little bit more details about your server-config..

Comment: Okay, I've removed the user's account. I'm now going to figure out the access type. Also, when I do "svn status" I see there is a 3rd party repository in use. Do I need to worry about that?

Comment: Host OS: CentOS 5.3
HTTP Server: Apache 2.2.3
Subversion: 1.4.2

Domains are virtual hosts, subversion repositories in each vhost directory above server root directory.

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove the user as opposed to disabling access? I don't know what SVN does with commits belonging to a user if you really remove it.

Answer (score 9):

Authorisation is done in one of three  ways depending on the Repository url:

**http://, https://**
Authentication is done in apache. The most common and simple case is Basic Authentication.  passwd file is created by apaches htpasswd-tool. Look into your httpd.conf for its location look for **AuthUserFile** directive. The file should not hold the old developers name.

**svn://**
Authentication is done in svnserve process. for this setup check the repositories configuration in its config-directory ( /path/to/repo/conf/svnserve.conf). In this files should be another file mentioned look for **password-db**. The file should not hold the old developers name.

**svn+ssh://**
Authentication is done via SSH, so you have to disable old developers system account or remove him from groups with read/write access to repository

Comment: There are many other ways to do authentication in Apache; for example you can configure it go to an LDAP server.

Comment: yes that is right, thanx for the comment I added this into my answer.. this is just a comprehensive answer regarding to different svn access methods.

Answer (score 5):

The answer of Peter Parker is a great answer. I want to add few more points to it.

After you locate passwd file, you have to remove the developer from the list. To do this use the following command:

```
htpasswd -D /path/to/passwd/file developer_username
```

To know what could be the SVN username of the developer, open the passwd file and check what are the usernames are found on that file. If you are unsure about which username, you can remove all users, as you said, no one is using it.

Answer (score 3):

### You remove the users from the host system first

The first thing to do is to remove the host system access. Possibly this is ssh, so remove his account and archive his directory, but we would need more information about your system to say for sure. There are multiple ways to get the power to write to an svn repository.

You can find out the different sort of credentials you may need to revoke in the [svn manual at this section.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.html) You might want to look quickly and see what's in  *conf/passwd* and *conf/svnserve.conf*.

Comment: svn does have its own private password credential option, for `svnserve`, so it's possible that just revoking host credentials is not enough

Answer (score 2):

How is your subversion server set up? If it's standalone, you should look in the `conf` directory of the repository.

If it uses SSH and the normal user accounts, then just removing the Unix user should be enough.

If it's using Apache, I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1):

To invoke svn password everytime, please follow the following steps. If you edit this file, it will be applicable for all the users. If you want to happen this only for you, revert the changes, and next time it will ask whether to store password please enter 'no'.

**Steps**

Edit `/root/.subversion/servers` file and uncomment the entries below to invoke the password:

```
store-passwords = no
store-plaintext-passwords = no
```

Answer (score 0):

Subversion doesn't really have the concept of users built in; authorization is handled separately. Typically this is done by the apache server svn is running in.

You'll need to look at your svn server configuration to see where the authorization is happening. There is a lot more specific information on this in the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), chapter 6.

Answer (score -5):

set up your iptables to restrict the user via his IP address.

- assuming he has a static IP, you can DENY all from his address.

Therefore, he cannot even look at the machine.

Comment: -1 IP can be changed at will, e.g. by using a different Internet connection. In fact, a static IP is typically a privilege that you have to pay extra for.

Comment: You are somewhat correct.  However, there is no harm in shutting an open window.  Sort of like saying "I won't remove they keys from the car's ignition because they can always hot-wire it"

Comment: @dar7yl: If we're going to do car analogies, here's another one: it's useless to lock the car doors if you leave the windows wide open.

Comment: How would you find out the hacker's home IP address before he has hacked your system? This answer makes no sense.